# Command like \item in different environment

Tags: enumerate, minipage

I already have the command

```
\newcommand{\atarget}[1]{
\noindent\begin{minipage}[l][0.49\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thetarget. \raisebox{3 pt}{\ul{\hbox{\hspace{1 in}}}}, leftmargin=1.5in]
\item #1
\end{enumerate}
\stepcounter{target}
\end{minipage}
}
```

I wish to create an environment in which `\newtarget` acts like `\item` and creates a new item formatted in the same way as `\atarget` would format it. Right now I am forced to use `\atarget{}` everytime I want a new item. For example, to produce 
[image: Output]
I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, top=0.6in, right=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\atarget}[1]{
\noindent\begin{minipage}[l][0.49\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thetarget. \raisebox{3 pt}{\ul{\hbox{\hspace{1 in}}}}, leftmargin=1.5in]
\item #1
\end{enumerate}
\stepcounter{target}
\end{minipage}
}
\begin{document}
\newtarget{\blindtext}
\newtarget{\blindtext} 
\end{document}
```

but would rather use

```
\begin{tg}
\newtarget \blindtext
\newtarget \blindtext
\end{tg}
```

for the sake of consistency (and lack of `{}`)

Comment: Will you need to cross-reference items?

Comment: I do not believe so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which uses the coffins provided by the LaTeX 3 project in place of a list. It relies only on functions published as public macros and considered stable by the developers. (That is, it doesn't use any of the newest experimental stuff - where the interface is likely to change - or anything internal - where things may change if the implementation of the public macros alters.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in, top=0.6in, right=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tgtermes}% times is deprecated
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_oneoneone_label_coffin
\coffin_new:N \l_oneoneone_content_coffin
\int_new:N \l_oneoneone_target_int
\int_zero:N \l_oneoneone_target_int
\dim_new:N \l_oneoneone_parindent_dim
\cs_new_protected:Nn \oneoneone_newtarget:
{
  \int_compare:nF { \l_oneoneone_target_int = \c_zero_int }   % Edit: \c_zero → \c_zero_int
  {
    \oneoneone_newtarget_out:
  }
  \int_incr:N \l_oneoneone_target_int
  \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_oneoneone_label_coffin { 35mm }
  {
    \rule { \l_oneoneone_parindent_dim } { 0pt }
    \int_to_arabic:n {\l_oneoneone_target_int} . ~ \rule { 25mm } {.4pt}
  }
  \vcoffin_set:Nnw \l_oneoneone_content_coffin { \textwidth - 35mm }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \oneoneone_newtarget_out:
{
  \vcoffin_set_end:
  \coffin_join:NnnNnnnn \l_oneoneone_label_coffin { T } { r } \l_oneoneone_content_coffin { T } { l } { 0pt } { 0pt }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { .49\textheight - ( \coffin_ht:N \l_oneoneone_label_coffin ) - ( \coffin_dp:N \l_oneoneone_label_coffin ) }
  \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_oneoneone_label_coffin { B } { l } { 0pt } { \l_tmpa_dim }
  \par
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {tg} {}
{
  \group_begin:
  \int_zero:N \l_oneoneone_target_int
  \dim_set:Nn \parindent { 0pt }
}
{
  \oneoneone_newtarget_out:
  \group_end:
}
\NewDocumentCommand \newtarget {}
{
  \oneoneone_newtarget:
}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \dim_set:Nn \l_oneoneone_parindent_dim { \parindent }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tg}
  \newtarget \blindtext
  \newtarget \blindtext
\end{tg}
\end{document}
```

[image: coffins as targets]

Comment: Thanks! However, it seems that this doesn't like to work with figures. Is there anything I can do to fix that?

Comment: Since there was no figure in your example, I obviously didn't realise that was required. Without an example, in fact, I have no idea what you're trying to do. I doesn't make sense to put a figure in a list.

Comment: Its fine. Sorry about the misunderstanding. I have already fixed it. Thanks!